# How dose forge calculate globalOffset in forge viewer by model derivative APIs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I want to aggregate the multiple rvt models in forge viewer by call

```

```
viewer.loadModel(firstPath, {}, (model) => {
    viewer.loadModel(secondPath, { globalOffset: model.myData.global});
    viewer.loadModel(thirdPath, { globalOffset: model.myData.global});
    viewer.loadModel(forthPath, { globalOffset: model.myData.global});
})
```

```

I know that:

- all rvt share origin point
- same unit
- boundingbox center to origin center point

but I want to know: how did viewer calc `globalOffset`, by base point or survey point?

Answer (score 0):

If the models share the same center, you don't need to transform (translate insert) them. Would suggest starting with this: **Preparing your viewing application for multi-model workflows** [Part 1](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows) and [Part 2](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows-part-2-model-loader).